# Drupal 8: Altering Search API queries

Tags: drupal-8

I'm working on a project which includes the following activated modules:

Drupal core 8.2.3
Database Search 8.x-1.0-beta4
Search API 8.x-1.0-beta4
Search API Term Handlers 8.x-1.0-beta4
Views 8.2.3

I have a list of nids which need to be excluded from the search result of the site-wide search. The search uses Search API and has been setup using Views.

The table in the database is: "search_api_db_default_index"
The field I wish to target is: "nid"

I wasn't able to get HOOK__search_api_query_alter or HOOK_search_api_results_alter to fire, so I am attempting to manipulate the query through HOOK_views_query_alter.

I have attempted to use both the "addWhere" and "addCondition" methods with the following syntax:

When using the addCondition method, I attempted

```
$query->addCondition('search_api_db_default_index.nid', $oneBadNid, '<>');
```

and

```
$query->addCondition('search_api_db_default_index.nid', $manyBadNids, 'NOT IN');
```

and when using the addWhere method, I attempted

```
$query->addWhere('AND', 'search_api_index_default_index.nid', $oneBadNid, '<>');
```

and

```
$query->addWhere('AND', 'search_api_index_default_index.nid', $manyBadNids, 'NOT IN');
```

Regardless of whether or not I prefix the field with the table name, searching always results in triggering the following notice:

**Unknown field in filter clause: 'search_api_db_default_index.nid'** .

It seems that the field name is always wrapped in an html encoded string representing a single quotation, but this occurs both when using double quotations or single quotations around the supplied table.field parameter.

I am not even sure that this is what is keeping me from altering my query, but it is the only thing close to an error which I have discovered in this process. It's also possible that I'm simply not supposed to be targeting the table in the manner written, but I did not find any documentation directing me to the proper methodology.

I would appreciate any insight into this issue! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Generally you can use

```
$fields = $query->getIndex()->getFields();
```

on the query to get an array of fields you can use within the search_api query.

Answer (score 1):

Piggy-backing off of Nebel54's comment, and attempting this on my own, you don't need to include the 'table' name when setting the addCondition. However, I did need to use hook_search_api_query_alter over a views-specific one.

```
function mymodule_search_api_query_alter(\Drupal\search_api\Query\QueryInterface &$query) {
  // Ensure field_myfield is being indexed
  $fields = $query->getIndex()->getFields();
  if (isset($fields['field_myfield'])) {
    $query->addCondition('field_myfield', 'myvalue', '<>');
  }
}
```